# Running Socket.io over Apache Reverse Proxy

Tags: node.js, apache, socket.io

I am trying to run NodeJS behind Apache and so far I am stuck with Socket.io issue.

I have no issue accessing the application directly, but whenever I accessed through my domain, I get this error thrown from socket.io:

```
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://example.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=X-hLU73t7ojk2zoRAAAB.
```

My Apache configuration is as follows:

```
     <VirtualHost _default_:443>
            ServerName example.com

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

            SSLEngine on

            SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key


            ProxyRequests off
            ProxyVia on

            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/socket.io            [NC]
            RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
            RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:8080/$1 [P,L]

            ProxyPass        /socket.io http://localhost:8080/socket.io
            ProxyPassReverse /socket.io http://localhost:8080/socket.io

            <Location />
                ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8080/
                ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080/
            </Location>
            #ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
            #ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/

            # BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
            #               nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
            #               downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

            BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                           nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                           downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    </VirtualHost>
```

I have also tried changing the `RewriteRule /(.*)` to `wss://localhost:8080/$1 [P,L]` but still thrown the same error. Can't seem to find any other answer to solve this.

I believe I am using socket.io 2.0, and on the client side it is connected as such:

```
var socket = io();
```

This is what bugs me,

[image]

It seems that some of the connection is going through but one is not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look into setting up a connection upgrade in Apache. That's what I needed to config nginx. Also, those http requests could be socketio serving the client file.

Also look into this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html

**Edit:**

The issue was solved with passing the ws/wss proxy as stated in mod_proxy_wstunnel. The apache virtual host config should have this:

```
         ProxyPass /socket.io/ ws://localhost:8080/socket.io
         ProxyPassReverse /socket.io/ ws://localhost:8080/socket.io
```

Instead of this:

```
        ProxyPass /socket.io http://localhost:8080/socket.io
        ProxyPassReverse /socket.io http://localhost:8080/socket.io
```

Comment: ws is for websocket. if we used polling at client side. then it will work ?

Comment: Thank you! Socket.io was falling back to long polling, now it runs properly over websocket. Do you know if fallback will work now if there is some problem at client side?

Comment: With this, it work but any path inside **/socket.io** such as /socket.io/socket.io.js will becomes unavailable. The recommended on [socket.io docs](https://socket.io/docs/v4/reverse-proxy/#apache-httpd) use mod rewrite with proxy so that you can use HTTP conditions before send them to `ws://` protocol only certain headers.

Answer (score 0):

Using Apache 2.4.6 on Centos 7

You need to do two things, first, on client-side initiate the socket-io in the following way:

```
var socket_io = io(wss://YOUR-IP/,{
        path: '/monitor-01',
        transports: ['websocket']
    });
```

Then, on the apache side, you must do the following configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    .
    .
    .
    ProxyPass /monitor-01 ws://localhost:4000/socket.io
    ProxyPassReverse /monitor-01 ws://localhost:4000/socket.io
</VirtualHost>
```

With these configurations you may have also, multiple socket connections on the same server, and for different applications.

Answer (score 0):

What I have could be slightly different and I've found that some solutions don't apply in every situation. Here is what I have with Apache as reverse proxy and works for me (with https).

Server: server.js

```
 const express = require('express');
 const app = express();
 const http = require("http").createServer(app);
 socketio = require("socket.io")(http);
 
 const socket_port = 5003;

 // @ Start server
 http.listen(socket_port , () => console.log('Socket server served on port: ' + socket_port));
```

**Apache config below.**

Add ProxyPass and websocket upgrade as below. Include it at the bottom of your virtualhost configuration.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>


    # ... 
    # ...
    
    # Add at the end of conf
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:5003/
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket
    RewriteRule /(.*) http://localhost:5003/$1 [P,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket
    RewriteRule /(.*) http://localhost:5003/$1 [P,L]

</VirtualHost>
```

**Client client.js**

Connect from NodeJS client application. Supports other clients like Flutter app  etc.

```
 var ios = require('socket.io-client');

 const externalServerAdress = "https://YOUR-DOMAIN-HERE";
 var socketClient = ios.connect(externalServerAdress, {
    reconnect: true,
    secure: true,
    rejectUnauthorized : false,
 });

 socketClient.on('connect', function (socket) {
    console.log('This client is connected to ' + externalServerAdress + ' 
 server with ID: ' + socketClient.id);
    
    // your rest of awesome code here
  
 });
```

#### Setup for HTTPS

Follow this thread where I described how ti implement it with https and Apache proxy upgrade.
https://github.com/rikulo/socket.io-client-dart/issues/319